# Kivy returns an error even though all dependencies are installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I had a problem with trying to run my first kivy code because of this error:

```
C:\Users\OnlyMe\PycharmProjects\sana\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/OnlyMe/PycharmProjects/sana/sana.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\OnlyMe\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-07-29_39.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) 
[MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 12, in <module>
from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
  File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and this is the code that I'm trying to run:
    import kivy
    kivy.require('1.10.1')

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label

class HelloWorld(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text="hello world")


HelloWorld = HelloWorld()

HelloWorld.run()
```

I tried uninstalling then installing the dependencies over and over again but it still returns the same error.

BTW I followed the instruction on how to install from here: https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html

My IDE is PyCharm and my OS is a 64-bit Windows 10 just in case it may help.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two libraries you should install. Your code works fine for me, but when I uninstall this two libraries I get the same errors so you need to install them

```
pip install pillow
pip install kivy_deps.sdl2
```